# Sitecore WFFM Form not working when inserted as a web control

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I created a form which works if I add it as control to Presentation --> Details. What I need to do on another page is inserting the same web form as a web control like this:

```xml
<wffm:FormRender FormID="{72857A3A-B6C5-48C0-995B-FA053C82870F}" runat="server" />
```

The form is shown on the page, but the validations report not filled fields, although they are filled.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at https://doc.sitecore.net/web%20forms%20for%20marketers/using%20web%20forms/insert%20a%20web%20form%20directly%20on%20a%20web%20page you've done everything right. Do you have some javascript errors? Or maybe some css file is missing?

Comment: There are no JavaScript or CSS errors. What I see when the form is integrated is this in Firebug: "GET visitoridentificationextension.aspx -
500 Internal Server Error". This is not present when the form is not in the page. What is strange is that the form is shown correctly, but even if I remove all validations from all fields there are validation errors. But it works when the form is added to the page as rendering in details --> presentation.

Comment: I used a workaround: I created a new page item and added the form to it via presentation details. I then inserted the new form page to the original page via iFrame. Not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. This is what you need to do.

`<wffm:FormRender FormID="{72857A3A-B6C5-48C0-995B-FA053C82870F}" FormTemplate="/sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Control/SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.ascx" runat="server" />`